# axios API not receiving data from express js nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express, rest, backend

> client

```
const {data} = await axios.create({baseURL:`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api`}).post("/seller/login",{         
        sellerMobile,            
        sellerEmail,
        password
    },headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        })
```

> server.js //Main file

```
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(cors())
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==="development"){
         app.use(morgan("dev"))
}
app.use("/api/seller",sellerRoutes)
```

> sellerRoutes.js  //Rout file

```
const router = express.Router()
router.post("/login",authSeller)
```

> authSeller.js    // Controller file

```
const authSeller = asyncHandler(async(req,res) => {    
const {email,password} = req.body

const seller = await Seller.findOne({sellerEmail:email})

if(seller){
    console.log("seller data",seller) // shows the data on backend console
    return res.status(201).send({
        _id : seller._id,            
        sellerEmail:seller.sellerEmail, 
        mobile:seller.mobile,
    })        
}else{
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error ('Invalid email or password')
}
})
```

I'm not receiving the data back in called API.

steps taken

- remove and add express.json
- remove and add bodyParser.json()
- remove and add bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})

Please help if required i would share the required files or even entire project.

Comment: using "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000", also just for reference.

Comment: You are calling the "/seller/register" end point from the client, but you show us the "/seller/login" endpoint in your server. Where is the code for the "/seller/register" end point?

Comment: its /seller/login

Comment: Then you should edit your question and fix that.

Comment: still not getting the data back in the api.

Comment: Your base URL is malformed

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/api
using this already

Comment: still not getting the data...

Answer (score 0):

You should change `app.use` to `app.post`, because your client is calling `POST` method

```js
app.post("/api/seller/login",asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
 const {sellerEmail} = req.body
 const seller = await Seller.findOne({sellerEmail})
 console.log("seller data",data)        //shows the data in seller
 return res.status(201).send({
        seller._id,
        seller.sellerEmail, 
        seller.mobile,
     })
})
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: noope!!
Does't work

Comment: I have added more information regarding the same..please lemme if it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the app.post as suggested above.
But in case you want to use the app.use, then you should do the Router, Controller Flow by keeping the Router, Controller logic in separate files which is a more cleaner approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: added more information about the question.

Comment: Does't solve the problem..